# Is container_fs_usage_bytes and container_fs_writes_total correlated metrics?

Tags: prometheus-node-exporter

I have Prometheus running in k8s, I have same exporter for container_fs_usage_bytes and container_fs_writes_total I would expect that values should correlate, so when I see disk consumption
I should see disk writes too. But currently they are showing different values.

container_fs_usage_bytes and container_fs_writes_total must be correlated?